# React chrome developer tools component selector?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, react-devtools

Is there a way to select a component in react developer tools chrome extension and have further operations on it in the console of chrome? I only found the `DOM` selector which navigates to the `elements` tab of chrome developer tools. 
[image]

Just like there is a component selector appears in Vue developer tools, where you can select a component and then you can access it in the console with `$vm0` variable. Same if I try with react, it gives this error in the console when I select the `App` component:

```
VM560:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $vm0 is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Is that missing in the react chrome developer tools?

Comment: Yes. Just select the component and switch to console and executee `$r`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to select the component with $r